# Остановка скрипта в PHP

Tags: php

Как осуществить остановку скрипта в определённом месте, не используя exit и die т.к. они убивают весь скрипт.

```
 if (!empty($_POST['r_name']))
    {
        if ($_POST['r_captcha'] != $_SESSION['secpic'])
        {
            $err_captcha = "ERROR CAPTCHA"; // Здесь нужно присвоить значение переменной, и остановить скрипт. Тоесть чтобы echo ":D"; не выводилось.
        }
        echo ":D";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант: проставлять метки. Если происходит ошибка, устанавливать метку ошибки и на каждом шаге проверять, не установлена ли эта метка.
Второй вариант: почитайте про try - catch. Если происходит ошибка, кидаете исключение. Если исключение поймано, обрабатываете ошибку.

Comment: Вашим методом сделал по первому варианту

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему это элемент проверки формы. Правильным шагом было бы:
 1. Если проверка пройдена, отправить письмо, и сделать редирект на страницу с текстом о том что сообщение отправлено.
 2. Если проверка не пройдена, переадресовать на страницу с ошибкой.

```
if (!empty($_POST['r_name'])) 
    { 
        if ($_POST['r_captcha'] != $_SESSION['secpic']) 
        { 
            $err_captcha = "ERROR CAPTCHA";
            header ( "Location: /error/" );
            exit();
        } 
        else
{
header ( "Location: /success/" );
            exit();

}
    }
```

Comment: Мне нужна не страница с ошибкой, а сообщение выше формы. Просто сообщений может быть несколько.

Comment: Что мешает на странице с ошибкой показать форму?

Answer (score 0):

чтобы echo :D не выводилось, пишем условие на значение как раз той переменной, присвоенное выше. Не соответствует ошибке - отображаем :D.
Соответствует - продолжаем скрипт, но перед любой логической конструкцией, которая может обвалиться из-за нехватки переменных или их некорректных значений, должно  стоять условие на всё ту же переменную, определяющую ошибку.
exit() здесь не нужен (хотя некоторые ошибки лучше фиксировать при помощи буферизации - ob_start), но нужны условия на бездействия всех функций. Возможно, нужно также продумать логику исправления ошибочной ситуации внутри скрипта - зависит от задачи скрипта.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись и без меток

```
if (!empty($_POST['r_name']))
    {
        if ($_POST['r_captcha'] != $_SESSION['secpic'])//если что то не валидно
        {
            $err_captcha = "ERROR CAPTCHA"; //присваиваем тут значение и делаем что хотим
        }
        else//иначе (если нет ошибок) продолжаем
        {
           echo ":D";
        }
}
```